# maven: deploy dependencies to alternate repository

Tags: deployment, maven-2, repository

Im trying to do something of a build promotion setup with our maven build.  Im doing this myself because the repository managers I've found dont quite fit the bill.

I want the process to work like this:
1. Development deploys ear and jar files to the 'dev' repository
2. The build team runs a build to grab those file, adds QA specific configuration templates,  packages the result into a zip file
3. Using the `<altDeploymentRepository>` option, the build team deploys the zip file to the QA repository
4. Deploy the dependent ear and jar files to the QA repository
5. After the QA cycle completes, the build team runs a build to download the (now tested) jar and ear files, add preprod specific configuration templates, and packages the result into a zip file
6. Using the `<altDeploymentRepository>` option, the build team deploys the zip file to the Preprod repository
... and repeat the process again for production roll-out

Everything works fine until step 4.  There doesn't seem to be a way to tell maven to deploy the **dependencies** to the alternate location.

So the end result is how do I get the **dependent** ear and jar files copied between repositories, and do so in such a way that the version information is intact and I can run regular builds against the them.

Switching of source and target repositories is done via a maven profile:

```
<profile>
  <id>qa</id>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>prddeploy</id>
      <name>build server repository</name>
      <url>${repoHost}/dev_repo</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
         <altDeploymentRepository>qadeploy::default::${repoHost}/qa_repo</altDeploymentRepository>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Where the 'dev' profile is the default so development needs no special steps, they just run `mvn deploy`.  The build team runs: `mvn deploy -P qa`  to start the qa deployment cycle.

I've tried using both nexus and artifactory as repository managers.  It doesn't seem to matter which one I use, but both are available if one or the other will make this process easier.

I know nexus offers a build promotion feature in its pro version, but based on the documentation the key deal breaker is that the staged repositories have to be `closed` before they can be used.  Our software has many different components and when fixing a bug in QA, we need to be able to redeploy only the changed components, and not the whole system.  The nexus staged repository setup doesn't seem to allow this.  If I'm reading it wrong, somebody please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider why the [Nexus Pro staging suite](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) appears to be restricting you.

The idea of "closing" a staging repo is to prevent any further changes to a set of artifacts being passed to QA for certification.

I would recommend one of the following solutions:

- Cut a smaller patch release, designed to be applied on top of the current release in QA.
- If your components are trully separate, consider releasing them as independently versioned components.

### Update

Artifactory has an [alternative way](http://blogs.jfrog.org/2009/11/search-based-promotion-staging-and.html) to manage staging and promotion of artifacts, using tagging. The details are not completely clear to me, but this solution might give the flexibility you're looking for.

Comment: The other thing I did not mention about the nexus staging repo is the process seems to take a lot of manual effort.  I need the process to be completely automated and scripted, as we frequently do `2-3 updates to QA per day`.  So requiring a build engineer to constantly create new staging repos for development to deploy into will not fly due to the amount of added overhead.  All the documentation I read gave steps using the nexus gui, which is not practical for the high volume we have.

Comment: The Nexus staging suite generates staging repositories automatically, just deploy. Additionally there is a Maven Nexus plugin for automating the actions: "close", "promote", "drop" and "release". The process can be fully automated. See the doco: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/staging-sect-managing-plugin.html

Comment: As to independently versioned components -- we already do this, but there is a given set of components slated for a given release, so for example, the Dec release may include v1.5 of the billing module and v2.3.1 of the SoundProcessor module.  There is no real dependency between those 2 other than they are in the Dec release.

Comment: well after going over the docs again, everything looks okay until we need to tell nexus how to decide which items to add to the staging repository.  There it falls apart, as really the only way is by the branch name from our SCM system, which is not visible in nexus.  The artifactory option looks like it will do the trick, but I will have to do a lot of testing to see